# When chopping off a DC current on its way to a load, what happens to the travelling pulse?

Tags: power

I am curious what happens if you draw DC power to a load, but as it approaches the load you chop the load connection say with a SSR or switch.

The power will be travelling near the speed of light, following the wire toward the load. When the load is chopped by a switch just before the pulse reaches it, will the power just keep travelling forward, according to Newton's Law of momentum (third law?). Or what comes of it?

Please let me know if you know the answer. Thanks

Comment: You need to formalize what you mean by "power", for one thing. Maybe you should look into transmission line theory.

Comment: What you're referring to is what falls under "transmission lines effects" which are all the effects that are ignored when you assume that the electricity propagates down the line instantly (or more specifically, the input end of the line "knows" what is happening on the opposite side of the line with no time delay and so can react instantly). More application specific terms include "antennas", "reflections", "ringing", and "termination". It is actually much more general than your example of "chopping just before the pulse reaches the end". The act of sending something down the line is enough.

Comment: There are no transmission line effects in an RLC circuit

Comment: The OP isn't asking about an RLC circuit. You're twisting his question into something it's not. The mere fact that his scenario includes modifying the wave just before it reaches the end of the line makes it a transmission line.

Comment: Where does it say the lines are a transmission line? I don't see a 50Ω impedance or the like anywhere. Most circuits are not matched transmission lines and transmission line effects are negligible. I've never seen anyone use a matched transmission line to control an SSR. If the lines are not matched, attenuation takes hold and it does not make sense to use a transmission line model

Comment: It seems to me that the OP's ultimate intent is to investigate the physics behind transmission lines and rather than just building a circuit. He does not use the term because he does not know the term, but he does describe it. In his quest to observe this effect, he has built a circuit specifically for this purpose. However, it seems that this circuit is inappropriate because the effect is negligible from an engineering perspective. Therefore, the appropriate response would be telling him how to make this effect more pronounced, rather than telling him to not treat it as a transmission line.

Comment: May be related, [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/17741/how-does-electricity-propagate-in-a-conductor) and [here](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/129626/since-cables-carry-electricity-moving-at-the-speed-of-light-why-arent-computer).

Comment: If the line is opened before the wave gets to the load, how would the wave know that there had ever been a load connected?

Comment: You get reflections.

Answer (score 1):

The source does not know that there is a load until the pulse has reached it and its effects have backpropagated to it. So the answer to your question is the same as to the question "what happens if I attach a generator to a transmission line open at the far end?".
This is standard transmission line theory.

Your generator won't even know that there once was a load at the far end.

Answer (score 0):

> The power will be travelling near the speed of light, following the
>   wire toward the load. When the load is chopped by a switch just before
>   the pulse reaches it, will the power just keep travelling forward,
>   according to Newton's Law of momentum (third law?). Or what comes of
>   it?

Nothing will happen, the misunderstanding that you have is that current is a substance, which it is not. For there to be current transfer, there *must be a voltage difference*. That means if the switch is off, there electrons would never start moving in the first place.

What really happens is the switch turns on, the voltage starts to go lower than the source, the electrons start to say to each other: "Hey, there is less voltage (electric field) towards the switch, I'm going to move in that direction", then they start to move. They bump into each other and into atoms in the wire (this is resistance). While they start to move they start to setup a magnetic field around the wire, this impedes the flow of electrons because the wire has inductance. As soon as the switch is off, the electrons stop moving, all of them, because there is nowhere for them to go because as soon as the switch is off, the voltage is the same.

Comment: This does not address the OP's question about transmission line effects. The statement "as soon as the switch is off, the electrons stop moving, all of them..." is only true if you assume instantaneous propagation time between both ends of the of the wire. When that assumption cannot be made then you see things like reflections and ringing back and forth down the line which literally are the two ends of the wire "communicating" and taking time to react to what is happening on the other end in order to agree on steady-state equilibrium.

Comment: Inductance is the limiting factor nothing moves at the speed of light and nothing propagates at the speed of light, since it's a switch with a wire it forms an RLC circuit there are no transmission line effects.

Comment: Yes, the wave does not propagate at the speed of the light (and the electrons themselves move much much much slower than that). But what you said still doesn't address the OP's question. The fact that there is distributed inductance and capacitance means there is ALWAYS transmission line effects. It's just whether or not you can observe them and whether or not they are actually significant enough to do anything about. The fact the OP's question involves a wave change before the signal has finished propagating automatically makes it a transmission line question.

Comment: @laptop2d You're treating this as an engineering problem, where it's really more of a physics question. I have a lot of respect for you as an experienced engineer and generally knowledgeable and helpful person, but I'm quite certain that Toor is right here.

Comment: @Hearth Does migrating this question to physics SE solve the debate?

Comment: Oh really? Maybe it's because I'm an engineer. And this is an electrical engineering site...

Comment: I don't think this type of answer is wholly inappropriate.  To some degree the raw physics are part of the engineering problem, so although I believe this question is suitable to physics SE, I don't think this is a terrible place for it either.  I think quite a bit could be added to it though, what makes some atoms more conductive than others, what voltage means in terms of electron density, billiard ball effect and propagation, the fact that electrons have inertia but it is tiny and not necessarily related at a given moment to the overall direction of current, thus induction dominates,

Comment: voltage effect of stopping a flow of electrons, and other stuff I'm not thinking of.  While engineering, one concentrates on the properties relevant to the use case (bulk current is much more relevant than what is happening to a given electron), but I do think I've had benefit from having an idea what is going on behind the scenes.  Most of that was learned as side information incidentally included in high quality diagrams in educational/ engineering videos played in class.  OP could benefit even from clarification of what exactly is moving(better to discuss movement of electrons than power).

Comment: What you are describing appears to create a faster than light communication system.  Put a switch at one end of a very long wire, and an ammeter at the other end.  Turn off the switch, and the current immediately drops to zero.

Comment: @SimonB A multimeter will not be fast enough to observe the drop. an oscilloscope will. And, no the current does not immediately drop to zero, it can't, the wire has inductance. Preform the experiment with an oscilloscope and you will see that the voltage has a decay in the ns range.

Answer (score 0):

You may have heard the phrase, 'inductance opposes changes in current, capacitance opposes changes in voltage'.

This is not the same thing as mechanical momentum, which isn't a consideration with electrons for ordinary electrical circuits. Yes, electrons have some mass, and like other subatomic particles can have some velocity too: they can be accelerated and smashed into things and give off energy in that collision (that's what an electron gun does, but that's another discussion.)

Rather, the case you describe alludes to the behavior of AC circuits and electomagnetic phenomena, itself an interesting physics topic.

Anyway, let's talk about what an inductor does from an EE standpoint, as this is where we are and it would seem to be the most applicable approach to your question.

When you pass a current through an inductor, a magnetic field builds up. In a steady-current state, the field is at a specific strength and size. Try to increase that current by upping the voltage, and the inductor will fight that increase with opposite voltage of its own until the field builds up to its new, higher strength.

Likewise, try to decrease the current by dropping the voltage, and the inductor fights that with opposing voltage as the field collapses until it settles to its new smaller and weaker field-state.

This fighting-the-field-change is called 'inductive reactance': the behavior of pushing *opposing voltage* to *changes in current*. It's a fundamental idea in understanding AC circuits (the other being capacitive reactance, which pushes *opposing current* to *changes to voltage*.)

The case you describe - opening a switch on a DC line - is a sudden change of current to zero. Because wires always have some inductance, what will happen is the magnetic field that has built up around the wire will collapse quickly, making a voltage across the wire (that is, inductor) with nowhere to go.

Given enough current and enough inductance the wire will see a voltage spike appear - possibly enough to arc across the switch or to something nearby. But this is because of the collapsing field, not because of the momentum of the electrons.